# Renaming multiple files to start with a capital letter

Tags: linux, command-line, rename

i'm trying to update my website to use CodeIgniter 3
but Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner or in other words - they must start with a capital letter.

For example, if you have the following library file:

```
application/libraries/mylibrary.php
```

... then you’ll have to rename it to:

```
application/libraries/Mylibrary.php
```

The same goes for driver libraries and extensions and/or overrides of CodeIgniter’s own libraries and core classes.

```
application/libraries/MY_email.php application/core/MY_log.php
```

The above files should respectively be renamed to the following:

```
application/libraries/MY_Email.php application/core/MY_Log.php
```

Controllers:

```
application/controllers/welcome.php -> application/controllers/Welcome.php
```

Models:

```
application/models/misc_model.php -> application/models/Misc_model.php
```

**How i can do that with command line ?**

thanks ,

Comment: [Linux Rename command uppercase first letter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14241691)

Comment: Check if you need to change reference to those filenames even inside the files too. PHP is [reported to be case insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5643544/3569208) for the functions declaration naming, even if it is a good practice to keep all as clear as it is possible. In case you need or decide to change even inside your library their names I think it's better to create a list of file on which operate and after to change their names and all the occurrences to them you find inside all the files you need.

Comment: How did you handle with that?

Answer (score 1):

With Bash 4, first enable additional globbing options:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Now make sure you call this only in the folders that contain the PHP files you want to rename. It will recursively look for `.php` files.

```bsh
for f in **/*.php; do 
  fn=$(basename "$f") # remove directory name
  Fn=${fn^}           # uppercase first letter
  echo mv -- "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$Fn"  # combine both
done
```

For the `MY_` files, you may need another run:

```bsh
for f in **/MY_*.php; do
  fn=$(basename "$f")
  Fn=${fn#MY_}     # remove MY_ from filename
  Fn="MY_${Fn^}"   # uppercase first letter and add MY_ again
  echo mv -- "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$Fn"
done
```

Remove the `echo` from these scripts to perform the renaming.

Comment: thanks slhck but how i can enable shopt -s extglob

Comment: You just type the command.

Comment: If shopt -s extglob isn't working then you're probably not in a bash shell. Execute bash first and then it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a little utility called `mmv`. You can uppercase the first letter as follows:

```
mmv "[a-z]*\.*" "#u1#2.#3"
```

And for the second case you mention (`MY_log.php`), you could solve this as follows:

```
mmv "*_[a-z]*.php" "#1_#u2#3.php"
```

or:

```
mmv "*_[a-z]*" "#1_#u2#3"
```

Comment: How does one obtain mmv? I have an `mmv` aliased to `zmv` from Zsh, but it doesn't appear to be the one you're talking about…

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x4055.htm